# Push UITabBarController onto another UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I have a `UINavigationController` in the root of my `UITabBarController`. I have another `UITabBarController` that I am presentint on top of the existing `UITabBarController`.

However, when I do, the `UITabBar` from the `UITabBarController` I'm presenting does not get pushed on top of the existing one from the original `UITabBarController`. Is there any way to get this functionality?

Comment: are you using Story Board or XIB files ? Or Just Code ?

Comment: @BishalGhimire Storyboard.

Comment: I have answered assuming, if you or I have misunderstood the step do  ask explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to take reference of root viewController (UINavigationController) 
Like

```
   UINavigationController *rootController = self.tabBarController.navigationController;
```

Or, If you added navigation controller in tabbar.
then

```
   UINavigationController *rootController = self.navigationController.tabBarController.navigationController;
```

Now, Create object of controller which you want to push.

```
UITabBarController *tabbarController;
```

And push into root controller

```
[rootController  pushViewController:tabbarController animated:YES];
```

Comment: This still doesn't solve the problem I'm having. That being where you take a `UITabBarController` > `UINavigationController` > `UITabBarController` and having the second `UITabBarControllers`.tabBar being pushed over the original UITabBarControllers.

Comment: this is the Code way. You said you wanted the solution for Storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

from you question this is what I have assumed.

1. First VC is TableView Controller which is root VC.
2. Which needs to push TabBar VC.
3. Which can further push to tableViewController.

StoryBoard Config
[image]

Simulator Output
[image]

Comment: Now that you have that setup, try pushing another `UITabBarController` on top of the existing one. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: But adding tabBar Controller in top of another tabar Controller does not make sens ! it should not be the flow. Flow should be tabar Controllers are holder of subviews ... still you can do but these steps and u just need to add one more VC. Where is the step you got stuck ?